# Getting blank image when using imgur's API

Tags: python, urllib2, imgur

I'm currently developing a small script to take screenshots and upload them to imgur using Python.

The code looks like this:

```
import time
import os
import ImageGrab
import urllib
import urllib2

time.sleep(1)
shot = ImageGrab.grab()
dir = os.path.join(r'C:\SAMPLE\PATH', 'Screen ' + time.strftime(r'%Y-%m-%d %H-%M-%S') + '.png')
shot.save(dir)

data = urllib.urlencode({"key":'MY_API_KEY', "image":urllib.quote(open(dir,'rb').read().encode("base64"))})

site = urllib2.Request("http://imgur.com/api/upload.json", data)
s = urllib2.urlopen(site)

print s.read()
```

I get a response from imgur but when I open the link I get a blank image (though its resolution is correct). I think the base64 encoding method may be off but I'm at a loss.

Comment: Are you sure the screengrab has been saved to the file you've read? Try it with another image with the name hardcoded.

Comment: @agf Yes, the file *is* there and I tried with a hardcoded path to another image with no avail. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `b64encode` from the `base64` module. I don't know why, but it gives different results:

```
from base64 import b64encode

(...)

data = urllib.urlencode({"key":'MY_API_KEY', "image":urllib.quote(b64encode(open(dir,'rb').read()))})
```

Comment: Still getting the same result.

Comment: I don't know what's wrong then... I searched for a few examples of python and imgur's JSON API and your code seems correct: http://garciat.info/easy-python-imgur-uploader http://pastebin.com/NiaJbhhP

Comment: @FernandoMartin If the answer worked out for you, you should `accept` it, since it gives some points to the one who took the time to write out the answer

Comment: @TankorSmash: I know, but the answer didn't work for me; the comment did, and it was by a different author.

Comment: @FernandoMartin Oh, good point. You'd still think though that his basic idea was the same though. In the end it's up to you. Off topic though, have you seen the `requests` module? Makes this stuff a ton easier.